# c++ modules do not compile with foward declaration

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have a State-Manager that is supposed to manage unique_ptr-smartpointers to objects derived from a Base-State (such as Game-State, Menu-State etc.). However, the Base-State needs to have access to functionality from the State-Manager, which potentially can cause a cyclic dependency. With Forward-Declarations and normal header files this can be avoided with the following approach, which works fine:

## Implementation with Headers and Forward Declarations

```
// StateManager.hpp

#ifndef STATEMANAGER_HPP
#define STATEMANAGER_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// receive all information about BaseState, so it can be used with unique_ptr
#include "BaseState.hpp" 

class StateManager {
public:
    StateManager() {
        m_states.emplace_back(std::make_unique<BaseState>(this));
    }
    ~StateManager() = default; 
    int provideImportantDataToStates();

private: 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseState>> m_states;
};
    
#endif // STATEMANAGER_HPP
```

```
// BaseState.hpp
#ifndef BASESTATE_HPP
#define BASESTATE_HPP

class StateManager; // just forward declare StateManager to avoid cyclic dependency
export class BaseState {
public:
    BaseState(StateManager* l_stateManager);
    virtual BaseState() = default; 
};


#endif // BASESTATE_HPP
```

Now i can include StateManager in the implementation-file of BaseState (BaseState.cpp) and access its functionality:

```
//BaseState.cpp

#include "BaseState.hpp"
#include "StateManager.hpp"

BaseState::BaseState(StateManager* l_stateManager) {
    l_stateManager->provideImportantDataToStates();
}
```

## Implementation with Modules that does not compile

Unfortunately, this approach seems not to be compatible with modules.

Here is the exact same implementation with modules, that refuses to compile:

```
// StateManager.ixx
export module StateManager;

import <vector>;
import <memory>;
import BaseState; 

export class StateManager {
public:
    StateManager() {
        m_states.emplace_back(std::make_unique<BaseState>(this));
    }
    ~StateManager() = default; 
    int provideImportantDataToStates() {
        return 5; 
    }
private: 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseState>> m_states;
};
```

```
// BaseState.ixx
export module BaseState;

class StateManager;
export class BaseState {
public:
    BaseState(StateManager* l_stateManager);
};
```

```
// BaseState.cpp
import BaseState;
import StateManager;

BaseState::BaseState(StateManager* l_stateManager) {

    l_stateManager->provideImportantDataToStates();
}
```

The compiler complains with the error messages:

- Error (active)   E3344   module file mapping for 'StateManager' is invalid [...] BaseState.cpp   3
- Error (active)   E0393   pointer to incomplete class type "StateManager" is not allowed  BaseState.cpp   7
- Error    C2665   'BaseState::BaseState': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types 3393

My guess is that the compiler makes no "logical" connection between the forward declared "class StateManager;" in BaseState.ixx and the "real" aka complete StateManager-class in StateManager.ixx.The forward declared StateManager seems to "overrides" the complete one included in BaseState.cpp with the command "#include "StateManager.hpp"

## Possible Solution that i do not like

The only working solution i found is the following one, which i do not consider as particularly nice to look at. Also i have not a good feeling about coupling StateManager and BaseState into the same module interface unit, since they are logically different things.

```
// StateManager.ixx
export module StateManager;

import <vector>;
import <memory>;


class StateManager; 
export class BaseState {
public:
     BaseState(StateManager* l_stateManager);
    virtual ~BaseState() = default; 
};

export class StateManager {
public:
    StateManager() {
        m_states.emplace_back(std::make_unique<BaseState>());
    }
    ~StateManager() = default; 
    int provideImportantDataToStates();
private: 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseState>> m_states;
};

BaseState::BaseState(StateManager* l_stateManager) {
    l_stateManager->provideImportantDataToStates();
}
```

This cannot be "the new way" of programming in C++...so i guess i am still using modules not the right way i the described scenario. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Modules have prevention against ODR violation. Say, two modules can define two different entities by the same name. And it won't cause ODR violation as long as they are not exported. This clearly interferes with forward declarations. Checkout modules partitions, it might solve your issue. You'd still have to put both classes in the same module - as they rely on each other - but you should be able to place them in different partitions.

Comment: “*Also i have not a good feeling about coupling StateManager and BaseState into the same module interface unit, since they are logically different things.*” But they aren’t. If you have to include onr to have the other, then they aren’t separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are not meant to be used like headers. The factors that drive you to split logically related code into different headers do not exist for modules. A module therefore maps to a library, not a single header file component of a library.

That is, whatever `StateManager` and `BaseState` are, they are logically part of the same library and therefore should be part of the same module.

From an organizational perspective however, it can be useful to be able to put code into different files, even if they are part of the same library.

C++ modules come from a single file: the primary interface unit for that module. However, this module may be composed of any number of interface partition units, which must be directly or indirectly included by the primary interface unit.

So rather than putting each class into their own modules, you put them into their own module partitions:

```
// StateManager.ixx
export module MyLibrary:StateManager; //Partition named StateManager

import <vector>;
import <memory>;
export import :BaseState; //Imports the BaseState partition

export class StateManager {
public:
    StateManager() {
        m_states.emplace_back(std::make_unique<BaseState>(this));
    }
    ~StateManager() = default;

    int provideImportantDataToStates() {
        return 5; 
    }
private: 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseState>> m_states;
};
```

```
// BaseState.ixx
export module MyLibrary:BaseState;

export class StateManager; //Must be exported here.

export class BaseState {
public:
    BaseState(StateManager* l_stateManager);
};
```

```
//MyLibrary.ixx
export module MyLibrary;

export import :BaseState;
export import :StateManager;
```

The reason why your separate module code didn't work is because your forward declaration of `StateManager` was in the purview of the `StateManager` module. So when the `BaseState` module declared a `StateManager` class, it wasn't declaring the *same class* as `StateManager`. Stuff belonging to one module cannot be redeclared as belonging to another module.